# Cursor in PL/SQL, my procedure doesnt work

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i have a problem in my procedure...in this case i want to raisy the salary to employees(Empleado) that have been working 5 years or more inn the store "Bodega"(...sorry about my english,i speak spanish XD).
First, i was thinking about select the ID's of all the employees that satisfy the condition (in a cursor) and then compare them to the ID'S in the EMPLEADO TABLE, if the same(the ID'S) then UPDATE the salary...it doesn't work with the IF - END IF (i put in COMMENTS) but without it. 
needing help...i am doing something wrong but dont know what it is.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE aumento_empleado(idBodega IN CHAR)IS

CURSOR c_empl IS SELECT E.idEmpleado 
             FROM Empleado E, Bodega B
             WHERE( MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate,E.fecha_contrato)>=5*12 
                    AND E.id_Bodega=B.id_Bodega 
                    AND B.id_Bodega=idBodega); 

idEmpl Char(8);
NO_EMP EXCEPTION;

 BEGIN

 OPEN c_empl;   

LOOP    
FETCH c_empl INTO idEmpl;
EXIT WHEN c_empl%notfound;

  IF c_empl%ROWCOUNT=0 THEN
      RAISE NO_EMP;
  END IF;   

--IF (idEmpl=Empleado.idEmpleado) THEN  
  UPDATE Empleado
  SET Empleado.Sueldo=Empleado.Sueldo + Empleado.Sueldo*0.05;   
--END IF;


END LOOP;   

CLOSE c_empl;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_EMP THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('No hay empleados que cumplan con las condiciones pedidas para la bonificacion' ) ;

   WHEN OTHERS THEN 
     dbms_output.put_line('Error: hubo un error durante la ejecucion del procedimiento' ) ;


END aumento_empleado;
```

Comment: Are you required to use a proc for this for an assignment or something? The proc is really far too complicated for the task.

Comment: Indeed - this is a single UPDATE query; SP is heavily overkill

Comment: I suspect you need to modify your UPDATE statement to something like `UPDATE Empleado SET Empleado.Sueldo=Empleado.Sueldo + Empleado.Sueldo*0.05 WHERE EMPLEADO.idEMPLEADO=idEmpl`.  And please don't apologize - your English is a lot better than my Spanish. :-) Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This single statement should work for your purpose

```
    UPDATE Empleado E
  SET E.Sueldo=E.Sueldo + E.Sueldo*0.05
  WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate,E.fecha_contrato)>=5*12 
  AND E.id_Bodega IN (SELECT B.id_Bodega FROM Bodega B)
```

Avoid using loops where they are not absolutely required.